# How can I incorporate custom authentication logic in Next13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When using pure React, I was running a following code when whole App first rendered to handle the authentication tokens:

```
const token = isAuthenticated()  // gets token from cookies/localStorage
if (token) {
    if (jwt_decode(token.access).exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
        if (jwt_decode(token.refresh).exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
            // if both access and refresh tokens are expired
            clearJwt()  // clears out token from cookies/localStrge
            navigate('/signin')
        } else {
            // if access token is expired but refresh is still valid, update the access token
            // refresh is call to rest api that processes authentication
            refresh({ refresh: token.refresh }).then((data) => {
                setJwt(data)  // set
                const decoded = jwt_decode(data.access)
                dispatch(
                    setAuth({
                        username: decoded.username,
                        id: decoded.id,
                        email: decoded.email,
                        first_name: decoded.first_name,
                        last_name: decoded.last_name,
                    })
                )
            })
        }
    } else {
        // if access token is valid
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token.access)
        dispatch(
            setAuth({
                username: decoded.username,
                id: decoded.id,
                email: decoded.email,
                    first_name: decoded.first_name,
                    last_name: decoded.last_name,
                })
            )
        }
}
```

So before rendering page components I was making sure there will be valid auth info. Now I want to implement similar routine in Next app (app router, not pages). I am not using Redux, since I was recommended to avoid it in Next app. Can you suggest best practices to implement this kind of thing?

I want to run similar thing at first run, then want this info to be persistent across pages. I am thinking of writing this in middleware.ts, but afaik I can't write async/await code in middleware, or can I? I wasn't able to find this info.

Second thing, how can I make sure to have this info on all pages? I mean, pages are server components, they have to somehow get this token info, so I can't just store this info in some context or redux. Most of the pages in my app will be using this token to send requests to REST API, so every page has to know about token info.

p.s. I am not using nextAuth, because my authentication is handled via requests to backend API. Afaik, nextAuth is like implementing this api in next server. Correct me if I don't understand something. And I apologize if I'm asking some trivial question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.